# Copy one column from one database to another

Tags: mysql, sql, database, copy-paste

I need to copy the content from a column in one database into the matching column in another, so that the same content goes in the record with the same ID. Something like the following pseudo stuff:

```
SET database2.table1.columnA TO database1.table1.columnA WHERE database2.id = database1.id
```

Comment: You have a database and a column, but where is the *table* in your scenario?

Comment: they are identical also, have edited to reflect this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [use JOIN in an UPDATE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
JOIN database1.table1 as t2 ON
   t1.id = t2.id
SET
   t1.columnA = t2.columnA
```

Comment: try that; I don't have mySQL handy so syntax may still be off, but that should get you on the right path.

Answer (score 19):

MySQL uses syntax:

```
update database1.table1, database2.table1
set database1.table1.columnA = database2.table1.columnA
where database1.table1.id = database2.table1.id;
```

Comment: Thanks. Syntax also compatible in Access (both tables in the same DB).

Comment: Tonight I love more MySQL than ever.

Comment: Here, the content of the `database1.table1.columnA` will be copied to `database2.table1.columnA`? or vice versa?

Comment: The SET-clause determines what happens. The `database1.table1.columnA`-gets the value from `database2.table1.columnA`.

Answer (score 4):

if not identical columns for other people you can use the below:

```
USE `old_database`;
INSERT INTO `new_database`.`new_table`(`column1`,`column2`,`column3`)
SELECT `old_table`.`column2`, `old_table`.`column7`, `old_table`.`column5` 
FROM `old_table`
```

Comment: Can you not do SELECT `old_table`(`column1`,`column2`) like you did in the INSERT?

Comment: The `FROM` throws an error for me saying incorrect table name.  But it's definitely the right name.  It seems a bit repeatative to say SELECT old_table and also FROM old_table could that be where the error is?

Comment: @Eoin not unless you want the possibility of data from different columns going to the wrong places. Its an additional step to make sure the data goes 1,2,3 as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works when your columns are not identical.

```
INSERT INTO `new_database`.`new_table`(`column1`,`column2`,`column3`)
SELECT `old_table`.`column2`, `old_table`.`column7`, `old_table`.`column5` 
FROM `old_database`.`old_table`
```

*Updated from https://stackoverflow.com/users/3746968/elgoots - Unable to properly paste this in a comment*